# Prove that perfect set is not countable

Tags: functional-analysis

A subset $S$ of a metric space $(X, d)$ is called perfect if it is closed and every point of S is an accumulation point of S. Prove that if S is a nonempty perfect subset of a complete metric space, then S is uncountable.

I would like to use Baire's theorem, and prove this by contradiction. However, if I assume perfect, I think S should be complete? Because if S is complete, S can't be countable (by Baire's theorem). I think the reason S is complete is because every Cauchy sequence in S converges to some accumulation points, which are in S since S is perfect, so S must be complete? Is this a correct thought?

Comment: Be careful. Any set can be given the discrete metric, which is complete, so completeness alone doesn't imply uncountability. You have the right idea though: $S$ is complete because it is a closed subset of a complete space, and you can use this and the fact that it has no isolated points to show it is uncountable (using Baire)

Comment: You're correct! I should have stated that since S is complete, and S has no isolated point, S can't be expressed as the countable union of nowhere dense set. Thus S is uncountable. Is it good now?

Comment: Seems good to me